# Data type for size of arrays and files

Tags: c++, types, fstream

What data type should I use for defining size of files to store file data in a dynamic array? Consider the following code segment:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

typedef uint64_t file_size_t;
typedef uint64_t file_pos_t;

int32_t ReadBytes(const std::wstring& file, file_pos_t pos, file_size_t numBytes, char*& readDataBuffer,
                file_size_t& bufferLen)
{
    using namespace std;

    bufferLen = 0;
    readDataBuffer = nullptr;
    ifstream is(file, ifstream::binary);
    if (!is)
        return -1;

    is.seekg(pos);
    if (!is)
    {
        is.close();
        return -2;
    }

    // Compiler warning in the following code line:
    readDataBuffer = new char[numBytes]();
    is.read(readDataBuffer, numBytes);
    bufferLen = is.gcount();
    is.close();

    return 0;
}
```

With the type that I have already defined, my compiler (MS Visual C++ 2017) gives a warning: `'initializing': conversion from 'file_size_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data` when building for 32-bit architecture. I used `uint64_t` because it is compatible with stream functions like `tellg` and `seekg` that receive or return `streamsize` (which is defined as `using streamoff = long long;` in `iosfwd.h`) and equivalent types.

How can I define `file_size_t` that removes this warning? Using `streamsize` also gives the warning I pointed to in my comment.

Comment: All your `is.close()` calls would be performed automatically by the destructor. However, you don't release the memory for the buffer. If you used a `vector<char>`, that would also be done by the destructor.

Comment: The memory for buffer is returned to the caller with the `readDataBuffer` argument. Please note that its type is reference to pointer.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that and that in and of itself is bad design. There's no reason for using raw pointers here. Doing it makes it only harder to get the program to be exception-save (and yes, in spite of you trying really hard to return magic numbers your code still has paths that exit via exceptions!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size_t` is the traditional type that's returned by `sizeof()` and which designates the size of some object, which can be an array, or a single object.

The fact that your data comes from a file is irrelevant. It still ends up in an array, with `size_t` being the type of the alleged size of the given array.

It is entirely possible that your operating system allows creation of files bigger than the range of values a `size_t` can represent. Presumably, if you are expected to read such a file into your array, you will not be able to read its entire contents due to your operating system's limitations. You will obviously have some means of dealing with that situation, but in all cases a `size_t` will always be a `size_t`.

Comment: "It is entirely possible that your operating system allows creation of files bigger than the range of values a size_t can represent". +1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't fix that warning, because it demonstrates a simple flaw in your code. On a 32 bit system, you can still have file sizes that exceed the range of a 32 bit integer. You must handle this case.

So, in short, the following steps are necessary:

1. Find the size of the file. This will use whatever type is used to represent the size of the file for the according system.
2. Then, check if you could possibly fit this into your memory space, i.e. whether it can be stored in a `size_t`. I'd suggest a simple `static_cast` to convert the value and a simple `static_cast` back to convert to the former value to make sure it didn't lose any information. Make sure that you don't trip over signed integer extension semantics!
3. Then, allocate the according amount of memory using that size. Using `new` is one (bad) way, but it mostly works.
4. Lastly, read the previously determined amount of data from the stream. Note that the size of the file can be both more or less than what you determined initially, as writes to it can happen concurrently. Consider what you want to do when that happens and how you want to detect that.

BTW: Depending on the size of the file and what you want to do with it, it might be easiest to just memory-map it. In particular simple read-only access is both simple and also much faster than copying the data around. I don't think that C++ comes with a builtin library for that, so you might have to write OS-specific code here. Using the existing code as a fallback, that should be relatively straightforward though.